# Package Organization in GWT(P)

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-platform

I recently discovered [GWT-Platform (GWTP)](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/) and am loving the architecture.

However, I'm finding that my packages easily get pretty bloated with classes (as three separate classes are generated with every Presenter you create, etc.). Of course, this can be a problem in any MVP GWT framework.

What do you recommend for organizing packages in GWT? I'm having a hard time finding logical places to segment my Presenters/Views/Events/Actions.

I've currently got something like the following, but I'm finding that I'm still getting dozens of classes in each sub-package which is difficult to navigate.

- client.presenters - stores all presenters
- client.views - stores all views
- client.uibinder - stores all UI binder classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Assume Package structure of GWTP project as below:
->Client package
com.gwtplatform.hplace.client

->Gin configuration package
com.gwtplatform.hplace.client.gin

Contain classes:
ClientGinjector
ClientModule

->Uibinder/View classes package
com.gwtplatform.hplace.client.view
file.java
file.ui.xml

->Presenter class package
com.gwtplatform.hplace.client.presenter

->Guice/Server package:
com.gwtplatform.hplace.server.guice

->Shared package
com.gwtplatform.hplace.shared
```